# Adding a record to an associated object throws and error Many-to-many Waterline sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

Sail Many-to-many association throws errors on save after adding associated object. Here is my modeling.

```
User: 

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    ...
    operations: {
      collection: 'operation',
      via: 'users'
    }
  }
};
```

operations:

```
module.exports = {  
  attributes: {
    ...
    users: {
      collection: 'users',
      via: 'operations',
    }
  }
};
```

on my user's controller, I have:

```
addPermissionToUsers: function(req, res) {
        Users.findOne(2).populate('operations').exec(function (err, user) {

            if (err) throw err// handle error
                // Queue up a record to be inserted into the join table
                 user.operations.add(1);
             Save the user, creating the new associations in the join table
             user.save(function (err) {       
                 if (err) throw err
                  res.json(user)
             });
        });
    }
```

Here is the error trace:

```
            if (err) throw err
                         ^
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
    at new WLError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError.js:25:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/model/lib/defaultMethods/save.js:188:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:550:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:544:17
    at _arrayEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85
```

Comment: Do you also have a `Users` model?

Comment: Yes, I do have a users.

Comment: Not `User`, do you have a `Users` model? This line (`collection: 'users',`) refers to `Users` model instead of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my God!! for anyone facing this issue you just need to run a migration so sails can automatically create the joint table for you. For me, I changed the config/model.js `migrate: 'drop'` and sails added the joint table and it works like charm.